# send notification to adminstrator if an a comment was added UGC

Tags: 2011, ugc

I'am using UGC to manage comment. I get comments in CMS and i can moderate them but i have a problem how can i send notification (Email for example) to administrator if there is an comment posted. Is it possible to notify administrator in this case.

This is my code

```
<form method="post" id="commentForm" class="clearfix">
    <input id="newCommentName" type="hidden" name="****" value='***'/>
    <label for="newCommentText"></label>
    <textarea id="newCommentText" rows="4" cols="30" name="addCommenttcm:***"></textarea>
    <span><span><input type="submit" id="B1" name="B1" value="Submit"/> </span></span>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Whom do you consider an administrator exactly? Are we talking about UGC users, Audience manager contacts or Tridion users?

Comment: UGC users when i said Administrator. I'am searching if it's possible to get submit event and send notification for some UGC users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no events triggered when a UGC comment is posted that you can handle in for example Tridion.

However, since you are posting from a web page, you can (and should) handle additional functionality directly from there.